# Swiper JS. Buttons on the third and subsequent pages do not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, swiper.js

Pls help with this problem, 'cause I don't really understand why is button "Back" doesn't work on page 2 and 3.

I want to make a website which will resemble a game menu, as in Deus Ex The Fall. I use for this swiper js, 'cause I need slider with parallax for all background. But something went wrong.

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: 'horizontal',
  
  parallax: true,
  

});

document.querySelector('.back').onclick = () => {
  swiper.slideTo(0)
}

document.querySelector('.page1').onclick = () => {
  swiper.slideTo(1)
}

document.querySelector('.page2').onclick = () => {
  swiper.slideTo(2)
}

document.querySelector('.page3').onclick = () => {
  swiper.slideTo(3)
}
```

```html
...
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testttt</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./swiperjs/swiper-bundle.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
    ...
<body>
            <div class="swiper">  
              <div class="swiper-wrapper">  
                <div class="parallax-bg" style="background-image:url(./images/panorama.jpg)" 
                data-swiper-parallax="100%"></div>
                    <!-- Slides --> 
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <h1>Page 0</h1>
                      <div class="buttons">
                        <button class="page1">Page1</button>
                        <button class="page2">Page2</button>
                        <button class="page3">Page3</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

On Page 1 button "Back" work correctly

```
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <h1>Page 1</h1>
                      <div class="buttons">
                        <button class="back">Back</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

But here none of the buttons works anymore

```
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <h1>Page 2</h1>
                      <div class="buttons">
                        <button class="back">Back</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <h1>Page 3</h1>
                      <div class="buttons">
                        <button class="back">Back</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>  
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="./swiperjs/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using querySelector to set the event listener. querySelector selects only the first instance of an element with that selector so none of your others are getting listened to.

Try using querySelectorAll instead. This will give you a collection of all the elements with that selector which you can iterate through to set the event listener:

```
const els = document.querySelectorAll('.back');
els.forEach ( el => {
  el.onclick = () => {
  swiper.slideTo(0)
}
});
```

though I guess you will want to alter the parameter passed in slideTo as relevant. (Perhaps use a for loop instead of the forEach).